# Select IEnumerable<object> from IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What I need to do is select list of nested elements, here is my query which `returns` `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>` here is my linq expression:

```
from a in (questions.Select(x => x.AnswerList).ToList())
                           select a.Select(x => x.AnswerBasicViewModel);
```

How should I do that to make it `return` only `IEnumerable<object>` instead of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>`?

Just to be clear in my sample I would like to get `IEnumerable<AnswerBasicViewModel>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `SelectMany` operator:

```
from q in questions
from a in q.AnswerList
select a.AnswerBasicViewModel
```

Or simply

```
questions.SelectMany(q => q.AnswerList)
         .Select(a => a.AnswerBasicViewModel)
```

Comment: isn't it better to add some `method syntax` version?

Comment: @KingKing already added this version :) yep, I think it much better

Comment: I got error on `SelectMany(x=>x.AnswerBasicViewModel)` said:
`The type argument for method ... SelectMany cannot inferred from usage.Try specifying arguments explicitly`. Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: wow, a little mistake in `syntax`, the `AnswerBasicViewModel` is not an `IEnumerable<..>`, I think you should perform the `SelectMany` first on the `AnswerList` and perform the `Select` then to extract the `AnswerBasicViewModel`.

Comment: @KingKing thanks, I posted my comment before you suggestion appeared)

Comment: @harry180 `Google` or `Bing`?

Comment: [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) used for projecting AND flattening queries. Select can do projection only

Comment: @KingKing or `Yahoo` :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I miss the day when I'm a newbie in `surfing net` and even hadn't known about `Google` before :), I used `Yahoo` for months :)

Answer (score 3):

SelectMany is the way to go here:

```
questions.SelectMany(x => x.AnswerList).Select(x => x.AnswerBasicViewModel);
```